# Java: How can I import Trident into my project?

Tags: java, animation

I'm trying to use the Trident animation library in my project. I've added the trident.jar to the build path in my Eclipse project but I'm still getting a build path error. The archive required for the library is missing.

Maybe I'm being stupid, but I can't seem to find anything like this on the website. I thought the .jar was the only thing I needed based on examples from around the net. And there doesn't seem to be a full Eclipse project to import either.

If I'm missing something silly, please let me know. Thanks!

Here is the exact error: Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
Archive for required library: '/home/josh/Software/Eclipse Java EE/Trident/trident.jar' in project 'SP-Reversi' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   SP-Reversi      Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trident.jar`is the only jar you need. The error message indicates, that your `trident.jar` is corrupted. Try to unjar the file:

```
jar -xvf trident.jar
```

IMHO this will produce an error. Try to download the jar once again...